# template operator visibility, gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, fold

I have this code, relying on a fold expression calling a very generic comparison operator:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename Iter_a, typename Iter_b>
auto operator<(Iter_a, Iter_b) {
    // original code makes more sense, I assure you
    if constexpr  ( std::is_same_v<Iter_a, Iter_b> ) { 
        return Iter_a();
    }
    else return Iter_b();
}

template <typename... Iterators>
using weakest_iterator = std::decay_t<decltype( (Iterators() < ...) )>;

int main() {
    using lit = std::list<int>::iterator;
    using vit = std::vector<int>::iterator;
    using wi = weakest_iterator<lit, vit, float*>;
}
```

I have two problems with this code:

The first is that g++ compiles it and clang++ (`-std=gnu++2a`) refuses to do so:

```
prog.cc:14:64: error: call to function 'operator<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
using weakest_iterator = std::decay_t<decltype( (Iterators() < ...) )>;
                                                               ^
prog.cc:19:16: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'weakest_iterator' requested here
    using wi = weakest_iterator<lit, vit, float*>;
               ^
prog.cc:6:6: note: 'operator<' should be declared prior to the call site
auto operator<(Iter_a, Iter_b) {
```

Do you have any idea why? I find particularly troubling that clang requests a definition prior to the call site at line 19, that it finds by itself at line 6.

The second is that, if I modify it to invoke my meta-function with pointer template arguments (`using wi = weakest_iterator<int*, float*, float*>;`, I get another error message, this time only with g++ since clang refuses to compile, that I find difficult to really understand:

```
main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class ... Iterators> using weakest_iterator = std::decay_t<decltype ((Iterators() < ...))> [with Iterators = {int*, float*, float*}]':

main.cpp:19:57:   required from here

main.cpp:14:75: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

     using weakest_iterator = std::decay_t<decltype( (Iterators() < ...) )>;
```

It seems that 1) the built-in overload of `operator<` is called (if there is anything such as this) over my ultra-generic one, and 2) that comparing an `int*` and a `float*` is considered the same as comparing a pointer and an integer.

Is it possible to make sure that my own implementation of `operator<` is chosen by the compiler?

Comment: "that comparing an `int*` and a `float*` is considered the same as comparing a pointer and an integer" -- That's just because `a < b < c` means `(a < b) < c`, no? Comparing an `int *` and a `float *` produces an `int` (edit: a `bool` of course. I was thinking of C). Comparing *that* to a `float *` is an error. This seems like a minor detail not relevant for your main question.

Comment: As to the second problem, I realize now that chaining comparison operators doesn't have the intuitive meaning and results in comparing a `bool` and a pointer / @hvd: thanks, indeed it is only a minor detail.

Comment: You cannot overload `operator <(int*, float*)` or even `operator <(float*, float*)`. I suspect error 2 come from that.

Comment: @Jarod42: so I must say goodbye to my fair `fold expression`? because if I can use my custom operator only on custom types, it won't cover every iterator, since pointers are iterators.

Comment: As usual, you can do it with extra layer: `(Wrapper<Iterators>() < ...)`

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve? Looking at your snippet, it looks like you are trying to use `operator<` to compare types in a strange way... There are easier ways to do this.

Comment: @Holt: I'm working on composite iterators, like `chain_iterator` or `zip_iterator` for instance. That's why I need to find the 'common denominator' of a list of iterator types, which would be the least powerful one. I could then deduce optimal `iterator_traits` and other behaviors.

Comment: @papagaga I do understand that, but I find it weird to use a comparison operator (`operator<`) to find the weakest type from a list of types. It is more conventional to use a template with `::type` typedefs for this kind of stuff, and usually easier to implement.

Comment: @papagaga [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/75fThc) is an example equivalent to your snippet without using `operator<` (you could replace `std::conditional` with specializations, I do not know what your actual implementation looks like). This feels more "standard" to me, and clean... But maybe that's just my opinion ;)

Comment: @Holt: your code is quite readable and clean, I agree. I'm looking for a less 'layered' style of code - by that I mean that you have one template `struct` and two specializations where I have only one operator. / you didn't notice that you changed the semantics though (right fold instead of left fold).

Comment: The first question is interesting, though the whole question seems too broad (you asked two questions)...

Comment: With which version of clang do you have issue ? with clang 3.8 c++1z, No issue with this template.

Comment: Notice that `vit` can be `int*` or custom class.

Comment: @Jarod42: clang 7.0. I've tested it with 3.8 c++1.z, and it doesn't accept `if constexpr`, so I'm a bit unsure of what you've tested.

Comment: I have to simplify code for `3.8` indeed, maybe I simplify it too much...